# I need help to return back to default state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
useEffect(() => {
 setShowProducts(true);
 if (_cloneArray(currentProducts) > 0) {  
   sortByPrice();
 }
 // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, []);

const defaultProducts = () => {
 let sortedProducts = _cloneArray(currentProducts);
 return sortedProducts;
}

const sortByPrice = (e) => {
 let sortValue = e.value;
 let sortedProducts = _cloneArray(currentProducts);
 if (sortValue === "lowest") {
   sortedProducts = _sortArray(sortedProducts, "locationPrice");
 } else if (sortValue === "highest") {
   sortedProducts = _sortArray(sortedProducts, "locationPrice", "desc");
 } else if (sortValue === "default") { 
   sortedProducts = defaultProducts();
 }
   setCurrentProducts(sortedProducts);
 }


return (
  <Menu menuButton={<MenuButton><CgSortAz size={20}/></MenuButton>} onClick={sortByPrice}>
    <MenuItem value="default">Default</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value="lowest">Price: Low to High</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem value="highest">Price: High to Low</MenuItem>
  </Menu>
)
```

So here I've created the sort items feature in ascending and descending order and I want to return to default state, which is not working after so many trials. Please I need some help here

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that once you sort an array and you override your variable there is no way to tell what the original order was.

```
const numbers = [9,1,8,2,7,3,6,4,5];
numbers.sort((a, b) => a - b);
console.log(numbers); // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

There is no way to turn back `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` into the initial value, because there is no info stored about the initial value.

To solve this we should keep the original array around.

```
const numbers = [9,1,8,2,7,3,6,4,5];
// `sort()` mutates the array, so we have to make a copy first
// to prevent `numbers` from changing
let sorted = Array.from(numbers).sort((a, b) => a - b);
console.log(sorted); // [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Now if we want to restore the original order we can simply do:

```
sorted = numbers;
// or create a copy `Array.from(numbers)` if you intent to mutate `sorted`
```

The same applies for React. A common way to solve this would be to have 2 states. One containing the initial/default array, the second containing the sorted variant.

```
const [currentProducts, setCurrentProducts] = useState(...);
const [sortedProducts, setSortedProducts] = useState(currentProducts);
```

When sorting, store the result as `sortedProducts`. If you want to reset `sortedProducts` simply assign it to `currentProducts`.

```
const sortByPrice = (e) => {
  let sortValue = e.value;
  let products = _cloneArray(sortedProducts);
  if (sortValue === "lowest") {
    products = _sortArray(products, "locationPrice");
  } else if (sortValue === "highest") {
    products = _sortArray(products, "locationPrice", "desc");
  } else if (sortValue === "default") { 
    products = currentProducts;
  }
  setSortedProducts(products);
}
```

Note that you should use `sortedProducts` in your view instead of `currentProducts`.

Since we never update `currentProducts` there is no real reason for it to be a state. This could just be a constant or a property (wherever the values comes from). If the values comes from an external API (or something async) it makes sense to keep `currentProducts` as an state, because it has to be set once fetched.

Here is an example that keeps the original order `NUMBERS` around and stores the sorted variant in a separate state `sorted`:

```js
const NUMBERS = [9,1,8,2,7,3,6,4,5];

function Numbers() {
  const [sorted, setSorted] = React.useState(NUMBERS);
  
  const sort = (e) => {
    switch (e.target.value) {
      case "asc":
        setSorted(Array.from(NUMBERS).sort((a, b) => a - b));
        break;
      case "desc":
        setSorted(Array.from(NUMBERS).sort((a, b) => b - a));
        break;
      case "default":
        setSorted(NUMBERS);
        break;
    }
  };
  
  return <React.Fragment>
    <div className="sort-actions">
      <button onClick={sort} value="asc">asc</button>
      <button onClick={sort} value="desc">desc</button>
      <button onClick={sort} value="default">default</button>
    </div>
    <p>{JSON.stringify(sorted)}</p>
  </React.Fragment>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<Numbers />, document.querySelector("#numbers"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="numbers"></div>
```